# SpriteKit Animation isn't loading when it supposed to be. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: swift, animation, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I'm making a simple game. Hero should jump over the enemies and if they collide - enemy should eat the hero. I have 4 types of enemies randomly spawning in front of a hero. I use the first sprite of every enemy-array as a main, the rest are for animation. But when they collide - nothing happens, it's still the first sprite. 
 That's how I'm doing it:

```
let mouseAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "mouse") 
mouseArray.append(mouseAtlas.textureNamed("mouse_0"));
mouseArray.append(mouseAtlas.textureNamed("mouse_1"));
mouseArray.append(mouseAtlas.textureNamed("mouse_2"));
mouseArray.append(mouseAtlas.textureNamed("mouse_3"));
```

Mouse is an enemy, cookie is a hero.

```
mouse = SKSpriteNode(texture: mouseArray[0]);
self.mouse.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) + self.cookie.size.width, self.cookieSpot + self.cookie.size.height + self.cookie.size.height / 2)
self.mouse.size = CGSizeMake(self.cookie.size.width + self.cookie.size.width / 2, self.cookie.size.height + cookie.size.height / 2)    

self.addChild(cookie)
self.addChild(mouse)
```

Then I'm applying physic bodies to them:

```
self.cookie.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: CGFloat(self.cookie.size.width / 2))
self.cookie.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
self.cookie.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Cookie.rawValue
self.cookie.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Pet.rawValue
self.cookie.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Pet.rawValue

self.mouse.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: self.mouse.size)
self.mouse.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
self.mouse.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Pet.rawValue
self.mouse.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Cookie.rawValue
self.mouse.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Cookie.rawValue
```

And then I'm trying to make an animation when contact begins:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    eatenByMouse(); eatenByHamster(); eatenByRabbit(); eatenByCat()
}

func eatenByMouse() {
    self.groundSpeed = 0
    self.cookie.hidden = true
 let animateAction = SKAction.animateWithTextures(self.mouseArray, timePerFrame: 0.1)
}
```

Like I said, there are 4 types of enemies but they are practically the same. What am I doing wrong with that? An I also interested, could I make physics body of enemies only on one side? I mean how can one make my hero eaten only if it touched enemies mouth for example? And if it touches the tail it would proceed rolling and jumping? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to run the `SKAction` after creating it.

```
func eatenByMouse() {
    self.groundSpeed = 0
    self.cookie.hidden = true
    let animateAction = SKAction.animateWithTextures(self.mouseArray, timePerFrame: 0.1)
    self.mouse.runAction(animateAction) // added line.
}
```

You can use `SKPhysicsContact.contactPoint` to detect point of collision.

Comment: Thank you! It helped! Can you help me with that one-side collision? Or, maybe with one more issue. When I coded appearance of enemies I thought it would be ok if they could appear in group but now I see that it's not very nice. How can I make a random range between enemies to appear? I tried but end up with something bizarre.  I'll update my question with spawning code

Comment: I got it. But I tried animation now and when enemy eats hero - every enemy on the screen run that eating animation. Why is that?

Comment: make the random spawning a new question in stack overflow. this is confusing.

Comment: you are running all the animations on contact `eatenByMouse(); eatenByHamster(); eatenByRabbit(); eatenByCat()` This is why all animations are executing simultaneously

Comment: Alright, I'll make random spawning a new question! Thank you so much! I guess, I'll make a switch statement for didBeginContact and it would be ok. Thanks again!

Comment: you have create separate categorybitmasks for each pet. `ColliderType.Mouse`, ColliderType.Hamster` etc.

Comment: I'm trying for two days and still cant make them not to execute animation simultaneously. I wanted to loop thru that functions but I can't do it. I think it's ok to ask that because it's related to my first question. How to make it? I created separate categorybitmasks and made an enum for them.

Comment: Someone here suggested to use bodyA & bodyB there, so it looks like this: `func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Cookie.rawValue &&
            contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Mouse.rawValue) {
                eatenByMouse()
        }
        if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Cookie.rawValue &&
            contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Rabbit.rawValue) {
                eatenByRabbit()` but it's not running animation now and not doing anything from "eatenBy..." functions